# How would I go about linking to an online store's stock (Amazon, Wal-Mart, etc.) to my own website?

Tags: php, html, css, sql, amazon-web-services

I'll just preface this question by saying I'm not looking for straight up code; I know that's generally frowned upon on this site. All I'm really looking for is someone to give me direction on what I need to do next.

Essentially what I had in mind for my website is checking various online retailers such as Amazon and Wal-Mart to see if particular products are in stock and available to buy online. That being said I have very little experience in languages other than HTML and CSS. I have a bit of SQL and PHP experience but nothing astounding. What would be my best course of action to accomplish this task? Or if there are any resources online that someone here could direct me to would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

See if those stores offer an API that you could use. If they don't which is likely because they don't really want other using their data... you will need to create a web crawler and have it patrol a list of sites and data mine the information you want.

Here is a link to amazon api --> http://webstore.amazon.com/API-Documentation-Resources/b/9437429011. I can't say this is exactly what you are looking for but it gives an idea of why type of API would be useful for your project.

If you don't know what an API is... check out --> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface and http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/api-good-technology-explained/ for more general information.